# JFrog Artifactory remote Docker repository items not cached

Tags: artifactory

I have a remote docker repository pointed at another JFrog Artifactory instance that I manage.  I can see Docker images in both the original Artifactory repository and in the UI of the remote repository, but when I click on the manifest for the images, it says "this item is not cached" and I cannot pull the image from the remote repo.  Is there a configuration item that I need to set to make sure the images get cached properly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting "Store Artifacts Locally" in the [Advanced Remote Repositories Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-OtherSettings). Check if it is selected.

Comment: I did set that to true, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything.  Are there any other settings that could cause this behavior?